Upgraded to 24.04 and perl is hosed
I can run perl but my modules are not found. Indeed, It can no longer see installed modules. I reinstalled perl and had to install perldoc again and that's not finding any modules. I successfully reinstalled one of the missing modules I need but my script still failed for lack of it. I even had to install Make. I keep getting this: 'bin/sh: 1: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: not found.' I can't find the path as to where the modules are installed. The instructions for doing that fail. I don't even know what module would certainly be installed so that I can search for that, and can't get a list of installed modules. I've never had this problem with perl. What happened and how can I fix it? I really don't want to have to go through the pain of reinstalling 22 again.
Oh, and I just had to reinstall gcc. (What? Really?)
Thanks

I'm not sure why you are having problems installing Perl modules.  Open a terminal and get typing the following.  Check if Perl is installed with:
perl -v

....and hit enter. If its installed it should tell you what version.  Almost all linux distros come with Perl pre-installed.
To install a module first install cpanminus:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cpanminus

To install the module type:
sudo cpanm nameof::module

...with the name of the module substituted for "nameof::module".

Yes, other than having to reinstall gcc and make and other things that should not have disappeared during the upgade, I found that I was using cpan rather than cpanm, which also needed reinstalled. (That's the part I most don't get: Why so many reinstalls after an upgrade.) Thanks.

Shoot. I need to come here only about once a year, if that. I don't see how to mark this as answered. :(
